# Keeping symbol in Map but not showing it in Legend using ArcGIS API for JavaScript

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I would like to customize the list displayed on the legend of the map but not delete it fro the Map.
Was able to get how to do it for desktop - but struggling to know how to do it in JS.
https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000016109

Am using ArcGIS v 4.15

```
this.renderer = {
  type: 'unique-value',
  field,
  legendOptions: {
    title
  },
  uniqueValueInfos: Object.entries(urlDict).map(([value, url]) => ({
    label: value,
    value,
    symbol: {
      type: 'picture-marker',
      url
    }
  }))
};
```

Comment: What sort of customizing? Changing the symbols or their labels or something more complex?